# Get names of dataframes in a list

Tags: r

How do you get the names of the dataframes inside a list? Not the columns inside the dataframe, but the dataframes themselves. So here is what I have:

```
mydata <- lapply(myfiles, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
fileNames <- list.files(pathx,pattern = "*.csv") 
names(mydata) <- gsub("\\.csv", "", fileNames) 
results <- lapply(mydata,myFUN)
```

The names, let's say are `[df1,df2,df3...]`. Now, depending on the name of the dataframe,`myFUN` performs a certain task. If I try this

```
myFUN = function(data){
  dataFrameName = substitute(data)
  ... #do stuff
}
```

`dataFrameName` holds `X[[1L]]` instead of `df1` and `X[[2L]]` instead of `df2`. What's a better way of getting the name of a dataframe inside a list?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the names?

Comment: There is some periodicity built in into the name of the file that I use to create a column of Logicals. For example, for df1 I do every i+1 row = TRUE. For df2, every i+2 and so on

Comment: print(names(mydata)) would give "df1" "df2" "df3" and so on

Comment: I meant the name of the file. I'm constructing an answer that extracts the periodicity element.

Comment: Wait, nevermind; can infer from the question. Misread :/

Comment: You can try `substitute(x, list(x = data))`

Comment: @RichardScriven that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply reading from a list of files, the data frames don't *have* names: the [[1]] and [[2]] you see are the list indices. If you're looking to perform operations that vary depending on the data.frame, it's going to get fairly ugly. The best you can probably do is something like:

```
myData <- lapply(fileNames, function(x){
    holding <- read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    holding$periodicity <- gsub("\\.csv", "", x) 
    return(holding)
})

results <- lapply(myDate, myFUN)
```

...where the decision-tree in myFun can now operate based on the values in each data.frame's "periodicity" column. It's an ugly hack (and not going to be the fastest thing: every time you modify a data.frame like that, you have to copy it, which is expensive).

Alternately, you can look at something like `Map` or `mapply` (think lapply, but it takes multiple inputs) and ignore the problem of naming the variables; you'd instead pass both myData and the names extracted via the gsub call into mapply, and end up with a function that has, to operate on, both df1 and the name "df1".

But, honestly, my advice would be that you're trying to solve the problem too far down the pipeline. While this will *work*, if there's data that you're dependent on to decide what analysis is performed, it should probably be included in the file, so that it can be read in, rather than included in the file name. Poke whoever is producing the files and ask them to be sensible ;p

Comment: From what I know, mapply is like sapply but with multiple arguments. The thing is, I would like something like lmapply, that is something that returns a list but takes multiple arguments.

Comment: @froy `mapply` can return a list (though it simplifies by default). `Map()` returns a list by default and has a slightly different parameter order. Both iterate over multiple arguments simultaneously.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks a lot! Using `mapply` helped me solve my issue. How do I respond or judge an answer if my question was basically not answered but I nonetheless solved my problem through the discussions in the answers? SO to the rescue

Comment: @froy If none of the user supplied answers fully addressed what you wanted, it would best to post your own answer to the question and then you can accept it. That's perfectly fine.